# Function for word by word string comparison in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, substring, sql-function

I need to write a SQL Server function that will take in two fields and perform a logical operation in this manner
- take first field value, split it into words
- make sure all of these words exist in the second field.

For example: the first field of `le chien` and the second is `le chien joue avec la balle`
The function would return true in this case, since all the words from the first one are in the second.

I could simply use `SUBSTRING`:

`SUBSTRING(field1, 0, 5)=SUBSTRING(field2, 0,5)`

But in some cases it would not work; if I have `field1` as `la maison (1)` and `field2` as `la maison (2)` `SUBSTRING(field1, 0, 5)=SUBSTRING(field2, 0,5)` would return true even though the strings do not match.

Increasing number of characters in some cases would work, but would not in others. So it all boils down to writing a function that will split the first string into separate words and ensure that all of them exist in the second string.

Can someone help me build a function or point me in the right direction? I'd really appreciate any help

Comment: If you want a string splitter, delimited split 8k by Jeff Moden is considered the best by many people, available here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Comment: Quick question @ElenaDBA if first field is "abc xyz" and second is " abc 123 xyz" then what should be the output.. is it true (meaning all words belong in second field ) or false?

Comment: Sagar Shirke, yes the output would be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CHARINDEX if you want to see if value1 exists in value2.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx

```
IF CHARINDEX(value1, value2) > 0  --found
```

If the words in value 1 can be in any order in value 2, then you can use the split function that JamesZ linked to in your question.  Once you add that function to your database you can use

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT  * 
          FROM    dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@value1, ' ')
          WHERE CHARINDEX(item, @value2 ) = 0) -- not found
```

Comment: Thanks! I am trying it out. So far working out nicely, provided that the words are in the same sequence

Answer (score 0):

can you check whether the following solution will fit your requirement

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/19/how-to-split-a-string-by-delimited-char-in-sql-server/

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END


----Select Statement
SELECT a.splitdata
INTO #firstSet
FROM fnSplitString('le chien', ' ') a

SELECT b.splitdata
INTO #secondSet
FROM fnSplitString('le joue avec la balle', ' ') b

DELETE a 
FROM #firstSet a
JOIN #secondSet b ON a.splitdata = b.splitdata

SELECT * FROM #firstSet


http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c5035
```